# How to properly release CVMetalTextureCacheRef and CVMetalTextureRef types

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, metal

Although Apple's documentation has samples that show how to create CVMetalTextureCacheRef and CVMetalTextureRef objects there is no information on how to release the memory related to these.

Answer (score 2):

For CVMetalTextureCacheRef objects (you created) call:

`CFRelease( _propertyName_ );`

For CVMetalTextureRef objects (you created) call:

`CVBufferRelease( _propertyName_ );`